# Removing ../ in the middle of a relative path

Tags: c#

I want to get from this

```
"../lib/../data/myFile.xml"
```

to this

```
"../data/myFile.xml"
```

I guess I could do it by manipulating the string, searching for `"../"` and canceling them out with the preceding folders but I was looking for an already existing C# solution.

Tried instantiating an `Uri` from this string and going back toString(). Didn't help. It leaves the string unchanged.

Comment: What are you then using this path fragment for? Loading the file? Building a URI? Something else?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw I'm generating a config file for another application that bugs out when it encounters such paths.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you may either need to parse/rebuild the path yourself, or use some kind of well constructed regular expression to do this for you.

Taking the parse/rebuild route, you could do [something like](http://ideone.com/SO46PI):

```
public static string NormalisePath(string path)
{
    var components = path.Split(new Char[] {'/'});

    var retval = new Stack<string>();
    foreach (var bit in components)
    {
        if (bit == "..")
        {
            if (retval.Any())
            {
                var popped = retval.Pop();
                if (popped == "..")
                {
                    retval.Push(popped);
                    retval.Push(bit);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                retval.Push(bit);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            retval.Push(bit);
        }
    }

    var final = retval.ToList();
    final.Reverse();
    return string.Join("/", final.ToArray());
}
```

(and yes, you'd probably want better variable names/commenting/etc.)

Comment: Mostly Path.GetFullPath(..) is a better way to go, but this technique has the advantage that it avoids the need to worry about exceeding MAX_PATH.

Answer (score 3):

You can always try to use:

```
Path.GetFullPath("../lib/../data/myFile.xml")
```

It behaves as you want with absolute paths but you might end up with strange behaviors with relative paths since it always bases itself from the current working directory. For instance:

```
Path.GetFullPath("/lib/../data/myFile.xml")   // C:\data\myFile.xml
Path.GetFullPath("../lib/../data/myFile.xml") // C:\Program Files (x86)\data\myFile.xml
```

Comment: This one involves obscure string manipulations too. But looks like I will have to resort to it in the end.

Comment: I wish there was a better way, and you could always do it manually like Rowland Shaw suggested, but the reason why GetFullPath only works with absolute path is because, while this sounds a little weird, there is no guaranty that "/a/b/../c" means the same as "/a/c". This is file system dependent and you could end up dealing with a file system that accepts ".." as folder names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to do this:

```
public static string NormalisePath(string path)
{
    return new Regex(@"\.{2}/.*/(?=\.\.)").Replace(path, "");            
}
```

Comment: I think your regular expression is not correct. using the path `hallo/../Welt/../a/b/c/../d` the result is `hallo/../d`, expected `a/b/d`